# How can I convert an iPhone application to universal application in a easy way?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an iPhone application developed with iOS and I need to convert the application to universal so the app can appear in the iPad apps section of AppStore.

It just so simple as changing the Device section in my project to universal or I have to re develop the app, create new views, etc?

Comment: You want to use the device at its fullest. So no, it isn't as simple as making the app target multiple devices, you need to ensure you are following Apple guidelines for each device.

The Apple Human Interface Guidelines are a good place to start when thinking of iOS development, or when converting an app for any device. Please take a look at this section specifically: `http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppDesign/AppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW3`. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It depends strictly on your app, but generally speaking, yes, you will need to create new views.

I mean, even if you want to keep exactly the same UI, chances are that it will be more convenient to provide iPad specific versions of your xib files, or adapt the views you created programmatically. This is due to the fact that the iPad is not simply larger: it has got different ratio (3:4 vs. 2:3) and this changes things completely. You might try to play with autoresizing settings for your views and grouping views to make the same xib work as desired on both screens, but I suspect that this is not so easy except for very simple interfaces.

In any case, this is not the end of the story.

Actually, you will not want a "good" app for iPad to have the same UI as the iPhone version, since the larger screen space really screams for using different layout and organization of the information and controls.

As I said, it depends strongly on your app (with games being the strongest exception to the above rule), but in most cases, your app will greatly improve if you redesign it specifically for the iPad, rather than simply adapting it (so that it is not shown in the 1x/2x mode).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes, just change the device family to Universal and you are done. But this would be pointless and you might even get rejected by Apple.

Take the time to actually create an app that takes advantage of the bigger screen. Use a split view controller and popovers or whatever is appropriate to your app.

Just making your main view bigger is a bad experience for your users.